# Disable web browser back button after login in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to unable user to go back to previous not login page after they login? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: If you are thinking of disabling back button in browser then it's ethically wrong to change normal behavior of a user browser.

Comment: What @SurajSingh said, but perhaps more important than ethics: your users will hate you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in C#

```
public void disablebrowserbackbutton()
{
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

client side

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preventBack() {
        window.history.forward();
    }
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload = function() {
        null
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works by adding the 1st code at Page_Load in c# and " if (Session["user"] != null) {Response.Redirect("")} "

Answer (score 1):

After login keep the user's details in the session... In the login page's pageLoad event check whether that session has any values, if it has any values then redirect the page to Home or Index page or whatever u want to load after login.

**In Login page's pageLoad:**

```
  string userID= (string)(Session["userID"]);
    if(userID!=NULL)
     {
      // code to redirect to home page
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it is not working at web browser back button if only use this code

Answer (score 1):

if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["LoginId"] == null)
                Response.Redirect("frmLogin.aspx");
            else
            {
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
                Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                            }
        }

Comment: Could you format your code and add some explanation?