# How to disable back button in aspx?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnresult_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button btn = (Button)(sender);
   Response.Write("<script>");
   Response.Write("window.open('studentresult.aspx?id=" + btn.CommandArgument + "','_blank')");
   Response.Write("</script>");
}
```

My home page `studententry.aspx`

In my home page, when I click result button, it goes to new window page and it shows student result.

But after that I will take a look at home page, it shows back button on the top of url address bar.

So I click the back button, again it goes to new window page and shows student result.

May I know, why the back button is active when I click result button?

Comment: above code is targeting blank so its opening new tab of browser, so when you open new tab its back button is disabled by default This might guide you http://stackoverflow.com/a/19971975/3583859

Comment: In new tab is disabled by default.. but in my home getting enable back button right...

Comment: try link in above comment, it might help you

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje: actually i m struggling how to add code in my existing code from your link..

Answer (score 0):

Write below method on your page code behind file and call it on page load event.

```
public void disablebrowserbackbutton()
{
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Add below Script in your client side file (`html`) inside `<head>` tag or if you using Masterpages before `contentPlaceHolder`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function preventBack() {
    window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
window.onunload = function() {
    null
};
```